# Rails - Devise - Redirect & Success message not occuring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, forgot-password

I am having success with changing my password in Rails, but the success flash notice is not appearing (unless I refresh the page, which the user shouldn't have to do). Is this a devise issue?

State of the page when I first arrive -

[image]

Page after I enter password and press 'Change My Password' -

[image]

Page after a refresh 
[image]

Comment: this is normal behaviour, if you are using ajax to change your password the flash message will not appear until the page reloads unless YOU MAKE IT APPEAR on your javascript file, I guess you are using ajax to change your password right? if you don't, do you want to make the flash message appear before reloading the page? it will appear for half a second before the page reloads

Comment: Please post your update password method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it, default rails behavior is to go to root_path. I added this code and it was fine

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:edit, :update]

  protected

  def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource_name)
    password_success_path
  end
end
```